# How can I create a font set from vector shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector

Is there any way to create real font set from the vector shapes created in Illustrator CS6?

I have a set of the vector shapes - 26 letters of English alphabet, I can copy every letter to make title etc, but I wanted to create a real font to type on keyboard as usual.

Comment: Update: You can now make a font directly from Illustrator & Photoshop with Fontself https://www.fontself.com 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Illustrator can not create fonts.**

You need font editing softer to create fonts.

[Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/)

[FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/)

[Glyphs](http://www.glyphsapp.com/)

There are others as well.

Comment: i meant can I import vector forms to these or other progs?

Comment: Yes. As long as they are simple, flat vector shapes.

Comment: so, can you provide any way to do that? which program of mentioned can import vector?

Comment: All of them can import simply via copy/paste. You should experiment with which app is most intuitive to you and fits your budget.